# I want to create a dataflow template from a python script

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I found this [script](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/blogs/tf_dataflow_serving/pipelines/stream_process.py) and I want to create a dataflow template from it but I don't know how. I also found this command

```
python -m examples.mymodule \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project YOUR_PROJECT_ID \
    --staging_location gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/staging \
    --temp_location gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/temp \
    --template_location gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME
```

for creating and staging a template, but it's really confusing for me.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you must prepare your script to be used as a template, for this you can follow the link provided by @JayadeepJayaraman [1].

Regarding the python command, it will allow you to create and store your template in the bucket selected in this paramter "**--template_location**", and the "**examples.mymodule**" refers to the path of the ***package.name_script*** for which you want to create the template.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates on how to create Python Dataflow templates.